# Fixing small broken area at lock plate of interior door jamb

Tags: doors, interior, jamb

My bathroom door has a minor issue at the lock plate of the door jamb. The main issue was that the screw area got forced in and I screwed in a nearby area that eventually broke.  I dont want to change the entire jamb for it looks like a small issue. So I thought of sawing a few inches above and screw a new wood area.  Want to see if there are better ideas to fix this.

[image: lock area issue]

**Update:**

Hi anybody " Dont see any solutions ?

My current solution is to saw/chisel the strike place area completely - about 1/2 inch. Put new wood block secured with screw on the sides leaving the center area for the strike place screws. Not sure if this will work. Anybody has experience if this will work ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What's the surrounding wall like? (A second, broader picture might help.) And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: What you're talking about is called a *strike plate*, by the way

Comment: Thanks - so the question is how do i fix a broken strike plate. The wood where the screw  goes is worn down and wont hold any more.  I was thinking of cutting a little above and replacing with a long one. But then realize that this may weaken the jamb.

Comment: Daniel - surrounding wall is intact - it is recently painted.  I wanted to change the lock and then noticed the strike plate is worn down.

Comment: Research “how to install a Dutchman in a door jam”